# DataTable is not a function TypeError while using angular-datatables for Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I'm getting TypeError while using angular-datatables in my code.

```
ERROR TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
at angular-datatables.directive.js:38
```

Code in the directive is:

```
 DataTableDirective.prototype.displayTable = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this.dtInstance = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Promise.resolve(_this.dtOptions).then(function (dtOptions) {
            // Using setTimeout as a "hack" to be "part" of NgZone
            setTimeout(function () {
                //Error in this line
                var dt = $(_this.el.nativeElement).DataTable(dtOptions);
                resolve(dt);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

What is the problem here? I installed the library and dependencies by:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install angular-datatables --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

Any idea?

UPDATE: Here is my tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
 },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
```

}

and tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,    
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "../node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check your tsconfig.json and its child files (e.g. tsconfig.app.json), if you have empty types array ("types": []) remove it.

Comment: I had one and I removed it, but no change.

Comment: Have you added all files in the angular-cli.json file?

Comment: I added                   "..\/node_modules\/jquery\/dist\/jquery.min.js",
"../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
                "../node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you sure the _this is correctly setted with your this of the component? .. have you tried something like:

```
DataTableDirective.prototype.displayTable = () => {
    var _this = this;
    this.dtInstance = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Promise.resolve(_this.dtOptions).then(function (dtOptions) {
            // Using setTimeout as a "hack" to be "part" of NgZone
            setTimeout(function () {
                //Error in this line
                var dt = $(_this.el.nativeElement).DataTable(dtOptions);
                resolve(dt);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Jquery and jquery extensions are global. Why do you think it is about closure problem?

Comment: cause every time i put function in my ts code i loose my this scope .. so maybe give a try to the fat arrow function .. hope it helps you!

Comment: ah ..be sure to include your datatable.js plugin in angular-cli.json file ..and be carefylly to use prototype

Comment: So anyone has solution. I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install angular-datatables --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

and then

add in angular.json

```
enter code here
 {
 "projects": {
    "your-app-name": {
    "architect": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"========>*
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",==============================>*
          "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"==============>*
        ],
```

restart  by using cmd

Answer (score 0):

Having both of them in angular.json fixed the problem for me

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
    "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
]
```